# ansible apt-key module with loop

Tags: loops, ansible, apt-key

I'm provisioning a system that requires multiple GPG keys to be added. I'm attempting to streamline the process and follow DRY principals.

I have apt packages installing from a vars list like so:

```yaml
- name: Install packages
  apt: name={{ apt_packages }}
```

Where my `vars.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
apt_packages:
  - tilix
  - terraform
  - ansible
  - opera
```

This works because the `apt` module accepts comma separated inputs and parses accordingly.

So I'm trying to achieve a similar process when using the `apt_key` module but I can't seem to get it to work. Here are a couple of attempts I've made:

```yaml
- name Add keys
  apt_key:
    url: url="{{ items }}"
    loop: "{{ gpg_keys }}"
    state: present
```

and

```yaml
- name: Add GPG Keys
  apt_key:
    url: url="{{ gpg_keys }}"
    state: present
```

Both throw different errors.

Is it possible to do something like this using the apt-key module? Obviously I'm trying to avoid having a separate caller for each key I want to add as there will be many keys and I'd like to be able to add additional keys later on by simply appending the list in `vars.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few small mistakes in your task.
The right way is this:

```yaml
- name: Add keys
  apt_key:
    url: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ gpg_keys }}"
```

- you already have the key `url`, so prepending `url=` is incorrect
- `loop` is an argument to the task and not to the `apt_key` module, so it needs to be indented to the level of `apt_key` (unlike `url` which is an argument to the model)

Sidenotes:

- You also need to make sure that `gpg_keys` contains a list, similar to `apt_packages`.
- The `name` parameter of `apt` accepts a list, as you define correctly in your `vars.yml`, no comma-separated string. (You are already doing it right)

Documentation:

- [apt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html)
- [apt_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_key_module.html)

Comment: Perfect thanks! One slight note when following your example i got: ``"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'items' is undefined`` switching ``url: "{{ items }}"`` with ``url: {{ item }}"`` worked